# R package xtractomaticxtracto_3D returns error: Failed to open file C:\WINDOWS\system32\tmpExtract.nc

Tags: r

I am trying to download data from  ERDDAP (Environmental
Research Division Data Access Program) server, using the examples in http://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/xtracto/R/using_xtractomatic_r.pdf

Following the first example given in the guide results in the error below the code:

```
require(xtractomatic)

str(Marlintag38606)

'data.frame':   152 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ date  : Date, format: "2003-04-23" ...
 $ lon   : num  204 204 204 204 204 ...
 $ lat   : num  19.7 19.8 20.4 20.3 20.3 ...
 $ lowLon: num  204 204 204 204 204 ...
 $ higLon: num  204 204 204 204 204 ...
 $ lowLat: num  19.7 18.8 18.8 18.9 18.9 ...
 $ higLat: num  19.7 20.9 21.9 21.7 21.7 ...

> tagData<- Marlintag38606

> xpos<-tagData$lon

> ypos<-tagData$lat

> tpos<-tagData$date

> swchl<-xtracto(xpos,ypos,tpos,"swchla8day",xlen=.2,ylen=.2)

Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  Failed to open file C:\WINDOWS\system32\tempExtract.nc.
```

Can anyone please tell me how to get around this error?

Thanks
Mike